# Auto hyperlink excel documents

Tags: excel, vba

Is this possible in Excel.

I have one excel sheet and an excel template.

I open this excel sheet. Whatever I type in the first column it should get converted to a hyperlink. So let's say I typed 'Roger' in A6. Roger should be hyperlinked. On clicking 'Roger' a new file with the name of Roger should be created from the template in a folderand should open for the user to edit. If the same filename as Roger already exists, open existing file.

Is this possible?

Comment: See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZA/exceldev/thread/fd0e6dc1-f71a-4671-beb7-91a276ecad2e

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with some VBA.

- First, you will have to use [event procedures](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx) to be triggered on change
- Then, you will have to create the file (a little search on the web)
- Then, you will have to replace the value of the `Target` cell with an `HYPERLINK` formula

Have a try by yourself and ask a question (or edit this one) when you are stuck on a specific issue.